Why I'm not getting the otp autofilled?
I'm currently implementing SMS autofill to capture an OTP from Firebase, but I haven't had success so far. I'm using both Bloc and sms_autofill in my setup. Despite trying various approaches, the OTP isn't auto-filling as expected. Here's the code I'm working with:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:pin_code_fields/pin_code_fields.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:responsive_sizer/responsive_sizer.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';
import 'package:timer_count_down/timer_count_down.dart';

import '../../application/auth/verify_otp/verify_otp_cubit.dart';
import '../../domain/core/configs/app_config.dart';
import '../../domain/core/configs/injection.dart';
import '../../domain/core/constants/asset_constants.dart';
import '../../domain/core/constants/string_constants.dart';
import '../../domain/core/services/analytics_service/analytics_service.dart';
import '../../domain/core/services/navigation_services/navigation_service.dart';
import '../../domain/core/services/navigation_services/routers/route_name.dart';
import '../../domain/core/services/storage_service/dynamic_link_storage_service.dart';
import '../../domain/core/utils/dynamic_link.dart';
import '../../infrastructure/core/enum/profile_state.enum.dart';
import '../widgets/rounded_arrow_button.dart';
import '../widgets/snackbar_alert.dart';
import 'login_with_phone_screen.dart';

class VerifyOtpScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String verificationCode;
  final String dialCode;
  final String phoneNumber;
  const VerifyOtpScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.verificationCode,
    required this.dialCode,
    required this.phoneNumber,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AppConfig appConfig = AppConfig.of(context)!;

    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => VerifyOtpCubit(VerifyOtpState.initial(
        dialCode: dialCode,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCode: verificationCode,
        apiBaseUrl: appConfig.serverUrl,
      )),
      child: const VerifyOtpScreenConsumer(),
    );
  }
}

class VerifyOtpScreenConsumer extends StatefulWidget {
  const VerifyOtpScreenConsumer({super.key});

  @override
  State<VerifyOtpScreenConsumer> createState() =>
      _VerifyOtpScreenConsumerState();
}

class _VerifyOtpScreenConsumerState extends State<VerifyOtpScreenConsumer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listenSmsCode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SmsAutoFill().unregisterListener();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _listenSmsCode() async {
    await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode();
    final String? appSignature = await SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature;
    print('App Signature: $appSignature');

    // Listen to the code stream
    await SmsAutoFill().code.listen((code) {
      print('Received SMS code: $code');
      if (code != null && code.isNotEmpty) {
        final RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'\d{6}');
        final match = regExp.firstMatch(code);
        if (match != null) {
          final otp = match.group(0);
          print('Extracted OTP: $otp');
          // Update the OTP field with the extracted code
          // You can call a method here to update the UI or state
          _updateOtpField(otp!);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void _updateOtpField(String otp) {
    
    context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().updateOtp(otp);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);

    return BlocConsumer<VerifyOtpCubit, VerifyOtpState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.backToAuth) {
          navigator<NavigationService>().goBack();
          context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().emitFromAnywhere(
                state: state.copyWith(backToAuth: false),
              );
        }
        // verify otp -> result - success
        if (state.isOTPVerificationSuccessful &&
            !state.isOTPVerificationFailed) {
          // nav to home
          print('navigating to home');
          final user = state.user!;
          Provider.of<AppStateNotifier>(context, listen: false)
              .updateAfterAuthChange(
            isAuthorized: true,
            user: state.user,
          );

          DynamicLinkStorageService.getStoredDynamicLink().then((value) {
            try {
              Map pathSegments = value ?? {};

              final profileState = user.fullName.isNotEmpty &&
                      user.dob.isNotEmpty &&
                      user.gender.isNotEmpty &&
                      user.tag != null
                  ? ProfileStateEnum.completed
                  : user.fullName.isNotEmpty &&
                          user.dob.isNotEmpty &&
                          user.gender.isNotEmpty
                      ? ProfileStateEnum.gender
                      : user.fullName.isNotEmpty && user.dob.isNotEmpty
                          ? ProfileStateEnum.birthday
                          : user.fullName.isNotEmpty
                              ? ProfileStateEnum.basic
                              : ProfileStateEnum.started;

              final route = (profileState == ProfileStateEnum.completed)
                  ? (value != null)
                      ? DynamicLinkUtil.getDynamicRoute(
                          pathSegments['category']!, pathSegments['id']!)
                      : UserRoutes.mainNavRoute
                  : profileState == ProfileStateEnum.gender
                      ? AuthRoutes.usernameRoute
                      : profileState == ProfileStateEnum.birthday
                          ? AuthRoutes.genderRoute
                          : profileState == ProfileStateEnum.basic
                              ? AuthRoutes.birthdayRoute
                              : AuthRoutes.basicInfoRoute;

              AnalyticsService().setUserId(state.user!.id.toString());
              AnalyticsService()
                  .setUserProperties(name: 'user_id', val: user.id.toString());
              AnalyticsService().setUserProperties(
                  name: 'phone_no', val: user.phoneNumber.toString());

              if (profileState == ProfileStateEnum.started) {
                AnalyticsService().logEvent(eventName: 'sign_up', paras: {});
              } else {
                AnalyticsService().logEvent(eventName: 'login', paras: {});
              }

              print('route $route');

              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100))
                  .then((value) async {
                navigator<NavigationService>()
                    .navigateTo(route, isClearStack: true, queryParams: {
                  'id': pathSegments['id'] ?? '0',
                });
              });
            } catch (e) {
              print('error $e');
            }
          });
          context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().emitFromAnywhere(
                state: state.copyWith(isOTPVerificationSuccessful: false),
              );
        }

        // verify otp -> result - failed
        if (!state.isOTPVerificationSuccessful &&
            state.isOTPVerificationFailed) {
          CustomScaffoldMessenger.clearSnackBars(context);
          CustomScaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
            context,
            message: state.errorMessage,
          );
          context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().emitFromAnywhere(
                state: state.copyWith(isOTPVerificationFailed: false),
              );
        }

        // send otp -> result - success
        if (state.isOTPSentSuccessful && !state.isOTPSentFailed) {
          CustomScaffoldMessenger.clearSnackBars(context);
          CustomScaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
            context,
            message: state.errorMessage,
          );
          context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().emitFromAnywhere(
                state: state.copyWith(isOTPSentSuccessful: false),
              );
        }

        // send otp -> result - failed
        if (!state.isOTPSentSuccessful && state.isOTPSentFailed) {
          CustomScaffoldMessenger.clearSnackBars(context);
          CustomScaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
            context,
            message: state.errorMessage,
          );
          context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().emitFromAnywhere(
                state: state.copyWith(isOTPSentFailed: false),
              );
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              OnboardingGradient(),
              SafeArea(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.h, vertical: 2.h),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 11.h,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        LoginScreenConstants.verifyNumberHeader,
                        style: themeData.textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 24.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: themeData.colorScheme.background,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 1.h,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${LoginScreenConstants.verifyNumberDescription} ${state.dialCode} ${state.phoneNumber}',
                            style: themeData.textTheme.bodySmall!
                                .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 2.w,
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().onGoBack();
                            },
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              AssetConstants.editIcon,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.h,
                      ),

                      PinCodeTextField(
                        controller: state.otpController,
                        appContext: context,
                        length: 6,
                        showCursor: false,
                        obscureText: false,
                        animationType: AnimationType.fade,
                        enableActiveFill: true,
                        enablePinAutofill: false,
                        hintCharacter: '-',
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        hintStyle: themeData.textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 22.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: themeData.colorScheme.background,
                        ),
                        textStyle: themeData.textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 20.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                        ),
                        pinTheme: PinTheme(
                            inactiveColor: themeData
                                .colorScheme.primaryContainer
                                .withOpacity(0.4),
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            inactiveBorderWidth: 0,
                            activeBorderWidth: 0,
                            shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                            fieldHeight: 8.h,
                            fieldWidth: 13.5.w,
                            selectedFillColor: themeData
                                .colorScheme.primaryContainer
                                .withOpacity(0.5),
                            inactiveFillColor: themeData
                                .colorScheme.primaryContainer
                                .withOpacity(0.5),
                            activeFillColor: themeData.colorScheme.background,
                            selectedBorderWidth: 0.6,
                            selectedColor: themeData.colorScheme.primary),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().onOtpChange();
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 1.5.h,
                      ),
                      state.showResendButton
                          ? InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().resendOtp();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                LoginScreenConstants.resendNow,
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .bodySmall!
                                    .copyWith(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize: 16.sp,
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .background,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      decorationColor: Theme.of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .background,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Countdown(
                              seconds: AppConstants.otpTimer,
                              build: (_, double time) {
                                return Text(
                                  '${LoginScreenConstants.resendAfter}${time.toInt()}${AppConstants.seconds}',
                                  style: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodySmall!
                                      .copyWith(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontSize: 16.sp,
                                        decorationColor: Theme.of(context)
                                            .colorScheme
                                            .onSecondary,
                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                            .colorScheme
                                            .onSecondary,
                                      ),
                                );
                              },
                              interval: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                              onFinished: () {
                                context
                                    .read<VerifyOtpCubit>()
                                    .coundownFinished();
                              },
                            ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: state.isLoading
                            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                            : RoundedArrowButton(
                                height: 6.h,
                                width: 6.h,
                                contentIcon: AssetConstants.longArrowRight,
                                isEnabled: state.isVerifyEnabled,
                                onTap: () {
                                  // if (!state.isLoginEnabled) {
                                  context.read<VerifyOtpCubit>().verifyOtp();
                                  // }
                                },
                              ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Could you provide some guidance on why the SMS autofill might not be working or if there are additional steps needed to ensure functionality?

Are you testing on Android or iOS?  Autofill is not possible on iOS.

No, I'm testing it on Android.
This is how my sms looks like '%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.'

The message should also contain a hash string that identifies your

that is not allowed in the firebase.
